# Function in Drupal to human-friendly URL

Tags: php, drupal

I'm using a manual SQL into view in Drupal. With the result of SQL, i will go to create links, but i want to create these links with human-friendly URL string.

> Sample
>
> ***word original***
>
> Blue Shirt
>
> **word, after function**
>
> blue-shirt

Does anyone know of any function within the Drupal to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not exactly sure what you are doing, but you may want to take a look at the [`l()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/l/6) function or the [`url()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/url/6) function and the [Pathauto module](http://drupal.org/project/pathauto) to make clean looking URLs.